# I want to access an class variable that are in a list

Tags: c#

```
public class Bullet
{
   public Vector2 position = new Vector2();
}

public class Traking
{
   public static List<Bullet> bullets = new List<Bullet>();
}

public static void FireBullet()
{
   Bullet b = new Bullet();
   Traking.bullets.Add(b);
}
```

And now i want to access position from the b instance that FireBullet created from the list. (I known that i dont give it a value in the example)

Comment: Do you want to access `position` from within `FireBullet`? Or from a calling context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
public static void FireBullet()
{
   Bullet b = new Bullet();
   Traking.bullets.Add(b);
   ....
   var bull0 = Traking.bullets[0]; // get first bullet
   var pos = bull0.positon;
}
```

or maybe

```
public static void FireBullet()
{
   Bullet b = new Bullet();
   Traking.bullets.Add(b);
   ....
   foreach (var bull in Traking.bullets){ // get all bullets
      var pos = bull.positon;
      ....
   }
}
```